# What value to give void properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this interface:

```
interface Props {
    close: () => void;
    disableButton: () => void;
    showPrompt: boolean;
    pol: string;
}
```

I'm trying to use it in a test. My problem is that I don't know what I should do with `close` and `disableButton`. They are just passed to that class so the state can be updated. What value do I give the variables for use in my `shallow`?

```
describe('<Reissue />', () => {
    it('calls reissue service', () => {
        const close = ???;
        const disableButton = ???;
        const showPrompt = true;
        const pol = '123456';

        const wrapper = shallow(<Reissue close={} disableButton={} showPrompt={showPrompt} pol={pol}/>);
    });    
});
```

Comment: it's a function, so `() => {}`?

Comment: Those aren't "void properties", they're "functions returning void".

Comment: If you're using jest, you can just pass `jest.fn()` to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`close` and `disableButton` are functions so you should pass functions to them, even if empty empty ones -

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Reissue close={()=>()} disableButton={()=>()} showPrompt={showPrompt} pol={pol}/>);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `void` keyword in this context is used to indicate that the function returns no value, hence you can just use an empty closure `() => {}`.

If you are using jest, you can also use `jest.fn()`, which will behave the same but has the benefit of capturing information that will help you during your tests (e.g. how many times the function have been called)

https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions